# Run-time error '1004' - Select method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to create a macro where all sheets will return to cell A1. In addition to this, if there are frozen cells on a sheet this macro would also scroll up and left on all sheets. The final piece of this code would return to the desired sheet.

As I step into this code I am getting this 1004 error at the beginning of the 3rd sheet. There are 8 sheets in this excel.

```
Sub Retun_to_A1()

'Retun_to_A1 Macro

 'returns selected cell to A1

 'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Do Until Cells(ActiveWindow.ScrollRow, ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn).Height > 0
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveWindow.ScrollRow + 1
    Loop
    Do Until Cells(ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn, ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn).Width > 0
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn + 1
    Loop
    Cells(ActiveWindow.ScrollRow, ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn).Select
    Next ws
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Next ws
    Sheets("JE Summary").Select
End Sub
```

updated

```
Sub Retun_to_A1()
'
' Retun_to_A1 Macro
' returns selected cell to A1
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.ProtectContents And ws.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions And ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1)
        
        Application.Goto rng, True
    End If
Next

Sheets(5).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Select` here, one option is `Application.GoTo`. Also note that you actually need to be able to select the cell in question... maybe something like the following:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.ProtectContents And ws.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions And ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1)
       
        Application.Goto rng, True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I know this was a couple of months ago but for some reason I have been running into errors where the code is clearing out the data in cell A1 on every tab. The code works great in the sense that all tabs scroll up the the most upper left position and scroll up if there are any frozen cells or tables or what not and returns to the desired tab, but it is not ideal that the data in cell A1 is being cleared out. I was wondering if you see anything here that would cause this. Thanks. I updated my code above

Comment: Hmmm. I don't see anything that would cause this behavior.